# Use Computer Modern font on Draft

Tags: draftin-com

I just started to use https://draftin.com/ it seems really cool, but I would love to customize it a little.

In the settings there is a text entry box where you can set the writing font for your documents. The page says a little below:

> By default we use source-code-pro at 1.125em and a light grey color. But you can use whatever you want and your system supports.

There isn't much more guidance for which fonts are supported, other than a few hyperlinks in the description of some other popular fonts. (See the pic below.)

How do I know which fonts are supported by my system? How would I add to this set of fonts if the one I want to use is not currently supported? My ultimate goal is to be able to use LaTeX's Computer Modern font.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my Chromebook, I was able to use the fonts listed on the settings page.

> Settings -> Customize Fonts...